# sortBy and orderBy, isn't working in my code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-collection

I want to get the latest timestamp. For some reason, when I try to use `sortBy` or `orderBy`, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Here is the codes that I tried:

```
public function getTest($id) {
    $data = test::where('user_id', $id)->sortByDesc('created_at')->get();
    // I also tried doing this
    $data = test::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    if(count($data)>0) {
        return view('test', compact('data'));
    }
    else {
        return view('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `$data = test::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();`

Comment: Any error message other than "it doesn't work" ? Might come handy to help you.

Comment: @HirenGohel yup it work, but why doesn't mine work? In the past, it was working fine

Comment: No error message @Amarnasan

Comment: is `test::` linked to the relevant model?

Comment: Please explain, what is not working? is it returning collection data but not in sort order as you required OR is it not returning any collection at all?

Comment: Accept Hiren Gohel's answer as working and close this question.

Comment: You can do it with id primary.
like `->orderBy('id', 'desc')`

Comment: What is this yar, you guys are missguiding all Stackover flow users.
`first()` returns the first record found in the database. If no matching model exist, it returns null.
please read manual first. @Amarnasan

Comment: `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` only gives latest recored which is added lastly. I think my answer is right but someone's downvoted it! @Rits

Comment: @Rits And that's exactly what I commented in his answer (now removed), that "first" would only return the first row. But the OP already told that it worked, and that's why I told him to accept his answer, because MAYBE he only wanted the first row...

Comment: Yes, that's why i have posted my answer! @Amarnasan I also thought that OP wants only first row. I am not wrong at my side.

Comment: @Amarnasan He is asking for order in both the cases he is described,
then it is not acceptable that he wanted to get first row.

Comment: @Dkna Is my answer is working properly for you as you test after i posted my answer?

Comment: @hiren If learners see this post they absolutely miss guide,Keep in mind for some vote or acceptance of answer you do not do like this.

Comment: Hey @Rits I don't do this for votes, I'll post my answer after OP confirm as he said that yup it's work! See his comment. And my answer gives latest row! First you learn bro then guide some other person!

Comment: If he accept then you can post wrong,
right??
Your answer is totally diffrent from his question, Thats why i am telling you brother.

Comment: Hey, not wrong! If he got result as he want how can you tell that it's wrong man! See his comment first then comment here!

Comment: @Rits Hey, enough with the ranting. The answer has been retired, you are the winner of the discussion, and the question is still unanswered, so if you can help the OP, go on, or continue with your life, whatever.

Comment: Perfect @Amarnasan I agree with you! Because we both are right at our end. Even OP also don't arguments!

Comment: Okay, Sorry brother @hiren gohel

Comment: It's ok, np. Happy coding!

Comment: @HirenGohel so sorry for the late reply, the code you gave me work, could you post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = test::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

This will order the rows in table by `created_at`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It retrieve 1 row only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the oldest `created_at` it would be easier to query like

```
$data = test::where('user_id', ,'=', $id)->oldest();
```

to get the user's test in descending order.

Here's a "pro" tip: You should set up a [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) between `Test` und `User`. And typehint your method (your route would look like `Route::get'(/users/{user}/tests', 'UserTestsController@index');`. You then could write your query like:

```
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $data = $user->tests()->oldest();

        return view('tests.index')
            ->with('data', $data);
    }
```