# Eloquent OrderBy and Take not working in a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to limit the number of entries returned in a hasMany relationship which works fine when either orderBy or take is used. However when they are used together, the results appear to be wrong.

What is wrong with this query?

Expected Results = 2 rows of data

Actual results = 2 rows of data

```
public function manual_ticket_log(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ManualTicketLog','manual_ticket_id','id')->orderBy('id','desc');
}
```

Expected Results = 1 row of data

Actual Results = 1 row of data

```
public function manual_ticket_log(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ManualTicketLog','manual_ticket_id','id')->take(1);
}
```

--ERROR HERE--

Expected Results = 1 row of data

Actual results = Empty array is returned

```
  public function manual_ticket_log(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ManualTicketLog','manual_ticket_id','id')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(1);
    }
```

Comment: check this answer I think it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198704/7902645

Answer (score 0):

intead of hasMany you can use HasOne to get only one record:

```
public function manual_ticket_log(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\ManualTicketLog','manual_ticket_id','id')->orderBy('id','desc');
    }
```

hasOne will get the first result only.